# how to keep website up when server resource is not available

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, ubuntu, mariadb

First of all I should say I'm newbie in server configuration and managment.

In my case mariadb has high cpu usage and oom killer close this service when resources are not available and website get down.

how to keep up website when oom killer kills a service or limit resource for services to prevent killing service by oom killer ?

I searched a lot about limiting resource but all soulution said I should optimize my services and application and I couldn't find soulution for prevent killing service by limiting resource.

Comment: Don't fix the symptoms, fix the cause. If your server doesn't have enough memory to hold your database, increase memory.

Answer (score 0):

I'd look into fixing the actual issue i.e either improve application performance or increase resources on your servers.

One other thing to note is high CPU usage doesn't cause oom kill. You can use `dmesg | grep -i "oom-killer"` or if you have atop command to look the past data when it happend

Answer (score 0):

High RAM usage can cause OOM.  How much RAM do you have?  What are the settings for `innodb_buffer_pool_size` and `max_connections`?  Are there other apps running in the same server?  If so, how much RAM do they need?

Lack of swap also contributes.  Add some swap space, if practical.  This won't solve the problem, but will (mostly) keep OOM from happening.  The downside is a significant slowdown.

High CPU usage does not cause OOM, at least not directly.  Turn on the slowlog with `long_query_time = 1`.  Then let's try to improve the slow queries.  More discussion:  [*SlowLog*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog)